Alignment between complex and simple meshes
I'm trying to align two mesh objects (.ply) via point picking, and I'm having some issues that are causing it to not transform either of the meshes.  I'm wondering if it's my approach.
Mesh #1 (Layer 0): created via photogrammetry, and is what I would call "complex" in that there are 22M faces.  This mesh has texture.
Mesh #2 (Layer 1): a simplified mesh file that I modeled via a CAD program of the general shape of the photogrammetry outputs, and is what I would call "simple" in that there are 3,178 faces.  This mesh does NOT have texture.
See the attached image for a visual.
Complex mesh (right) and Simple (left)
OVERVIEW OF OBJECTIVE:
I suppose I should explain what I'm trying to do here: I'm looking to align these two meshes, so that I can then transfer the texture from the photogrammetry-based one to the CAD-based (simple) one.  I guess you could say I'm looking to bake the textures.
I've attempted both the point based alignment and the manual based one, and neither have worked.
I have tried using both .ply and .obj formats, and both result in the same error stating there are no overlapping meshes.
